# Passing a pointer to a member function across C++ modules

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Given two classes: `X` and `Y`. `X` contains a member of type `Y *` and passes the pointer to its member function to the instance of `Y`. So in C++ it looks like this:

x.h

```
#pragma once

class Y;

class X
{
public:
    X();
private:
    Y *y;
    void myfunc(int);
};
```

x.cpp

```
#include "x.h"
#include "y.h"

X::X()
{
    this->y = new Y(*this, &X::myfunc);
}

void X::myfunc(int dummy)
{
    dummy = dummy;
}
```

y.h

```
#pragma once

//#include "x.h"    // this would fix the issue!

class X;

class Y
{
public:
    Y(X &x, void (X::*pMyCallback)(int));
    ~Y();

private:
    X &x;
    void (X::*pMyCallback)(int) = nullptr;
};
```

y.cpp

```
#include "y.h"
#include "x.h"

Y::Y(X &x, void (X::*pMyCallback)(int))
    : x(x), pMyCallback(pMyCallback)
{
    (x.*pMyCallback)(3);
}

Y::~Y()
{
}
```

When I run this code, Visual Studio 2015 raises the exception: "MYPROGRAM.exe has triggered a breakpoint". Sometimes it crashes with Access Violation exception.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    X x;
    return 0;
}
```

It has come to my notice that the issue is somehow related to compilation units as it doesn't crash if I define `X` and `Y` in the same file. Moreover, if I include the declaration of `X` (i.e. "x.h") into "y.h", it won't crash either.

Is there a rationale for such behavior?

Comment: Just tried your code, with both the command-line compiler and GCC.  It works for me, assuming you have `#include "x.h"` in your main source file.  Perhaps the issue is being caused by a project setting?

Comment: @JustinTime In MinGW it also works, but it crashes in Visual Studio (tried 2008 and 2015). Project settings are default ones for a console application.

Comment: Hmm... try compiling it from the [Developer Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx); from the source directory, use `cl -EHsc main.cpp x.cpp y.cpp`.  If it works, then the code itself is fine.

Comment: @JustinTime It crashed when I tried to run the created .exe

Comment: Strange.  I'm honestly not sure what's going on, it compiles for me.  Hmm... one of the compilers I tested it with was MSVC 2010; I had to change `y.h` slightly, by specifying `nullptr` as a default parameter in the constructor instead of a default value for `pMyCallback`, as `Y(X &x, void (X::*pMyCallback)(int) = nullptr);` and `void (X::*pMyCallback)(int);`.  Maybe try that, and see if it works then?  Only thing I can think of.

Comment: I don't have VS2010 to see how it works there, but it seems depending on the version, the crash may occur irregularly. VS2008 just gave me this: "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention." Often the error is different. The crash becomes more obvious if we use two callbacks. [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45873423/memptr-vs2008.zip) is the test project (VS2008) with two callbacks.

Comment: Hmm... remembered [something I'd seen on the MSDN before](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ck561bfk.aspx), took a look, and tried something; it appears to be working.

Comment: I think I've found the answer, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that when defining pointers-to-members after the class is declared, but before it's defined, MSVC has to guess at the class' inheritance model.  There are four ways to handle this:

- Use the MS-specific keyword `__single_inheritance`, `__multiple_inheritance`, or `__virtual_inheritance` in the declaration `class X;` in "y.h", to force it to use a specific model.  Of these, `__single_inheritance` is the most efficient, but only usable when the class doesn't have multiple or virtual inheritance; since `X` has no base classes, this is fine.

  ```
  // y.h

  #pragma once

  //#include "x.h"    // this would fix the issue!

  class __single_inheritance X;

  class Y
  {
  public:
      Y(X &x, void (X::*pMyCallback)(int));
      ~Y();

  private:
      X &x;
      void (X::*pMyCallback)(int) = nullptr;
  };
  ```
- Use the MS-specific pragma [`pointers_to_members`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/83cch5a6.aspx), for the same reason.  Again, we can use "single inheritance", which is the most efficient choice.

  ```
  // y.h

  #pragma once

  #pragma pointers_to_members(full_generality, single_inheritance)

  //#include "x.h"    // this would fix the issue!

  class X;

  class Y
  {
  public:
      Y(X &x, void (X::*pMyCallback)(int));
      ~Y();

  private:
      X &x;
      void (X::*pMyCallback)(int) = nullptr;
  };
  ```
- Change the **Pointer-to-member representation** option in the IDE; I'm not sure how to do this, unfortunately, since I can't find the option.
- Specify the command-line option [`/vmg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yad46a6z(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Yes, you made it! Thank you. However, in my opinion MS team had better fix it as the other compilers do not require any special magic to make it work.

Comment: @mentalmushroom According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713) blog post, and a little test with Clang & GCC, it looks like the underlying issue is that MSVC is unusually aggressive with optimising pointers-to-member-functions, while other compilers are relatively lax.  This aggression saves space (but breaks code depending on pointers-to-members always being the same size) if the class is defined in the same translation unit as the pointer, but causes issues if it isn't.

Comment: Conversely, Clang and GCC _always_ assume the worst-case scenario (their equivalent of `__virtual_inheritance`, I believe, but I'm not 100% certain about that), even if a definition is available, as far as I can tell.  \[[When using command-line option `-fms-exceptions`, Clang can also accept the MSVC inheritance model keywords, however](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#single-inhertiance-multiple-inheritance-virtual-inheritance).]

Comment: Now, MS could easily fix this particular issue with a simple patch, without needing to change the actual, underlying problem (which is good, because people tend to start writing code that depends on their errors, so fixing them can break stuff); they just need to modify `cl` to asusme `__virtual_inheritance` for any pointer-to-member generated while no definition is available. I'm guessing that either they're afraid that changing the default behaviour will _also_ break a ton of other peoples' code, or they just haven't received enough complaints about it to prioritise it over the other issues.

Comment: (For example, on a 32-bit system (with 4-byte pointers and `size_t`s), their worst-case scenario pointer-to-member is 16 bytes, `__virtual_inheritance` is 12 bytes, `__multiple_inheritance` is 8 bytes, and `__single_inheritance` is 4 bytes.  On a 64-bit system (with 8-byte pointers and `size_t`s), it seems a bit cleaner: the worst-case scenario is 24 bytes, `__single_inheritance` is 8 bytes, and the other two are 16 bytes.)

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that [type deduction determines the proper inheritance model on a per-member basis, instead of based on the class' inheritance model](http://rextester.com/WDVR5791).  Tested this program with both 32-bit and 64-bit MSVC, and it deduces that `&E::fe` requires `__multiple_inheritance`, `&F::ff` requires `__virtual_inheritance`, and the others only require `__single_inheritance`.